# {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"} in fosoauth bundle

Tags: symfony, oauth

I tried to to use the FOSOAuthServerBundle for authenticating the users respective to their access token.

I did all the settings as per the link: http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/

As an output I receied the client id and the client secret key but I am confused about the grant_type..what values does it hold??

And while running this in browser: http://external.apostle.digibiz.com/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token?client_id=1k1x8xpqbjnogs88cso0gwwk4848oocsscsgwcwowcck4840s8&client_secret=3ntf3p6h6c6c04g4o08ggkgcwc0co0sk804gwckow88g0ggck0&grant_type=client_credentials

the following is given as error: 
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}

How can I solve this error????

Answer (score 5):

You can find list of supported grant types at [oauth2 repo](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/oauth2-php) in class [OAuth2](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/oauth2-php/blob/master/lib/OAuth2/OAuth2.php#L194-L199). Here are they:

```
/**
* Grant types support by draft 20
*/
const GRANT_TYPE_AUTH_CODE          = 'authorization_code';
const GRANT_TYPE_IMPLICIT           = 'token';
const GRANT_TYPE_USER_CREDENTIALS   = 'password';
const GRANT_TYPE_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS = 'client_credentials';
const GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN      = 'refresh_token';
const GRANT_TYPE_EXTENSIONS         = 'extensions';
```

Grant type specifies how client can be authenticated in application. Detailed explanation can be found in [OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) but it's spread around the document. Precise meaning of each grant type based on my knowledge of [OAuth2 Server bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle):

- `authorization_code` - client is identified and authenticated by `code` parameter obtained earlier from server
- `password` - client is authenticated by user's credentials: user and password
- `client_credentials` - client is authenticated by it's own credentials (the ones you've provided during client creation)
- `implicit` - one step authentication. Not recommended unless you know what you're doing
- `refresh_token` - client is authenticated by refresh token provided in original authentication. OAuth token issued earlier becomes invalid
- `extensions` - ???

You can provide more than 1 `grant_type` per client. Also I recommend you to read great article [OAuth2 Simplified](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified)